# How to find offset for an element of kernel struct?

Tags: linux, kernel, structure

In the linux Kernel, I need to find a offset of member variable of kernel struct. I tried to use offsetof but it claimed that I had an undefined struct. Is it possible to do in userspace? since kernel struct is not allowed to use in userspace, I can't see to find it using offsetof. Is there another way to find this?

Answer (score 0):

In the kernel, use:

```
#include <linux/stddef.h>
```

It is defined as:

```
#define offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER) __compiler_offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER)
```

This is used throughout the Linux kernel.

A similar construct probably exists in the libc includes, if you are trying to use this in user mode.

Comment: I'm aware of offsetof but I cannot use kernel struct to find an offset in usermode. if you try to declare like struct task_struct task, it won't compile because task_struct is undefined

Comment: I found this in a glibc source file.  It might work:    #define offsetof(Type, Member) ((size_t) &((Type *) NULL)->Member)